# jfreechart histogram with dates

Tags: java, jfreechart, histogram

I want to display some dates in the X axis of a histogram chart, but i don't understand how i can do it

with this code i can create a simple histogram with couples of x-y values, but they can olny be numbers, not date:

```
DefaultTableXYDataset dataset = new DefaultTableXYDataset();
    XYSeries serie = new XYSeries("Andamento consumi", true, false);

    serie.add(30, 8.3);
    serie.add(31, 7.1);
    serie.add(1, 8.7);
    serie.add(2, 6.0);
    serie.add(3, 11.9);

    dataset.addSeries(serie);

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createHistogram("Grafico di prova", "Giorni", "Consumi", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,true);

    ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Titolo finestra", chart);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Is there a way to insert dates instead of numbers?

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with dates use a `TimeSeriesCollection` or `TimePeriodValuesCollection` dataset instead of `DefaultTableXYDataset`.

Comment: I am trying to understand how this TimeSeriesCollection works. I see i have to add a TimeSeries, which has tio be constructed using a RegularTimePeriod.. I am a bit confused... Can you please provide some example code? Thanks

Comment: @Maik, "How to constructor or use TimeSeriesCollections" is a different question.  Please create a new post for it.  Thanks

Comment: ok i have created it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119244/how-to-construct-and-use-timeseriescollections