# How to construct and use TimeSeriesCollections

Tags: java, jfreechart, time-series

I want to display some dates in the X axis of a chart, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118684/jfreechart-histogram-with-dates) it is said that i have to use a TimeSeriesCollections object

It seems that i have to add a TimeSeries to the TimeSeriesCollections, and that the TimeSeries has to be constructed using a RegularTimePeriod... 
I am a bit confused...

Can you please explain me what i have to do?
If possible can you provide some example code?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`TimeSeriesCollections` are made up of `TimeSeries` objects

Use this method to add series to the dataset: `addSeries(TimeSeries series)`

When creating `TimeSeries` objects. Fill them with the time and values.  Here is a rough example:

```
TimeSeries ts= new TimeSeries("Name of Series");
ts.addOrUpdate(new Year(2008), 42);
ts.addOrUpdate(new Year(2009), 51);
ts.addOrUpdate(new Year(2010), 97);
ts.addOrUpdate(new Year(2011), 45);
```

For getting the Axis to display the dates nicely, you will have to do something like this:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
DateAxis axis = new DateAxis();
plot.setDomainAxis(axis);
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"));
```

Comment: There´s something wrong with that. In the chart the years are represented by some strange values (between 1.200.000.000.000 and 1.300.000.000.000). How can i for example insert a specific date instead of a year?

Comment: For a specific date use a different RegularTimePeriod class. I used Year in my example but you can use any of these: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod.html

Comment: I have found the way to use a Day instead of a Year. But i still don't get what you wrote in the last code... What is that "plot"?

Comment: @Maik, Added the plot variable to the second example.